K8S - How to avoid simultaneos monolith replicas on Kubernetes/ensure only one pod is always running in a deployment for a monolitic application
A monolitic application deployed on Kubernetes must only have one instance running at all times since it was built in a non-scaleable way and having multiple instances, even for a brief second, might corrupt either the database or on-disk data.
The application must:

At all times, only have 1 pod/process across an entire cluster (even in the case of a malfunctioning node)
In case of a node drainage, it must start a new pod ONLY after the old pod completely stopped
It must automatically restart in cases of failures/health check failures

We all know that loading monolitic applications in K8S is generally a bad practice, since building a monolitic, non scaleable application is by itself a limiting approach to future developments. That said, what is the best way to satisfy the above requirements, aside from fixing the codebase?
I could find some similar threads, but they don't really answer the question:

kubernetes - How to ensure running pods are terminated before new pods are created for a deployment
Always run one instance of Kubernetes pod
Can a deployment ensure that there is never more than one pod running?

Some solutions I could think of (that I have yet to implement):

Have some kind of "Mutex" mechanism on a ConfigMap that with a sidecar pod checks for other instances of this pod (has the downside that it won't detect them in case of node failures, but the application might still be running correctly on the failed node)
Have a mutex on the application's main PVC (or database) to ensure that if the other application still is running, the main program won't start. (has the downside that the application might be temporarily blocked, for example due to a temporary network issue, and might start again later, thus creating inconsistency)



The application must:

At all times, only have 1 pod/process across an entire cluster (even in the case of a malfunctioning node)
In case of a node drainage, it must start a new pod ONLY after the old pod completely stopped
It must automatically restart in cases of failures/health check failures


This is the exact semantics that Kubernetes StatefulSet provides.
The StatefulSet provides at most one Pod semantics.
But yes, note, as you said, this is not recommended and you will have downtime during upgrades of both the application and the node.

Hello Jonas, thank for your answer! This does indeed solve most of the requirements, but in case of a malfunctioning node (e.g. kubelet stops sending updates to kubeapi) you will still have some sort of corruption. But, seeing your answer made me think, maybe it would be possible to do something with a PodDisruptionBudget to sort of manage this manually? Wouldn't be the best approach but it would avoid data corruption at the expense of high availability.

@F.Alessandro what corruption are you talking about? StatefulSet is designed specifically for this semantics.

This is the usecase from the question: "A monolitic application deployed on Kubernetes must only have one instance running at all times since it was built in a non-scaleable way and having multiple instances, even for a brief second, might corrupt either the database or on-disk data.". You could say the "Corruption" comes from a badly built application/architecture.

@F.Alessandro I have answered that StatefulSet has "at most one Pod" semantics. But you say that you will have corruption in that case, where do you get that from?

If 2 instances of the application write on the same database table, they overwrite each other's data. The software is not meant to be used concurrently, so I understand that it is a bad idea to deploy it on k8s.

@F.Alessandro if you use StatefulSet as I wrote in my answer, you can use only one instance and you avoid that problem.

Even if a kubelet crashes and it stops sending updates to the control plane?

@F.Alessandro that is a case that Kubernetes cannot control, so there is no Kubernetes solution that can be guaranteed in that case.

Yeah, I suppose there is nothing that can be done, even in case of a malfunctioning node there is a probability that the sidecar pod may get killed. Well, thanks for the answer about the ReplicaSet! I'll try it out as that seems the best solution for now.

In cases like this, usually I use one of the following solutions.

Deployment with Recreate update strategy

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate

[...]


Use a StatefulSet

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 1

The drawback is the downtime during the updates/restart.

In your first case, when using Deployment, you can certainly have situations with multiple pods, e.g. when a node lose network connection for some time.
